# Lights on BufferGeometry not correct

Tags: three.js

I got a BufferGeometry that uses MeshLambertMaterial and VertexColors. When I apply lights as the gif below shows, the lights gets distorted when the BufferGeometry consists of different sizes of faces with the same color. If I use different colors for each face with smaller faces (1x1) the lights looks good. I've tried to calculate faceNormals but that doesn't solve the issue.

Anything I miss?

[Here is a gif showing the issue](https://media.giphy.com/media/xUA7aO4fMOaOBeVB60/giphy.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using vertex lighting, instead you probably want per pixel lighting.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per-pixel_lighting

http://www.learnopengles.com/tag/per-vertex-lighting/

It is my understanding that three.js almost exclusively focuses on PBR lighting/shaders. With this mindset, i'm not even sure what lambert should be used for. Either way, Lambert only supports per vertex lighting, not per pixel, so you will always get these artifacts from interpolating against different topologies. There are no limitations that prevent this from working different, it's just by design.

`MeshPhongMaterial` on the other hand does per-pixel lighting, but because of all the physical correctness, you might have a hard time removing the specular term, leaving only the lambert.

If you opt for this, you might find yourself having to do something like this

```
var myBlackTexture = obtainTextureThatIsBlack()
var myMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({... specularMap: myBlackTexture})
```

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/10808

Summary:

> Anything I miss?

You missed the arbitrary three design caveats :) It will remain a mistery why this material exists as is, and why it doesn't just have a flag to flip between vertex/fragment lighting.

Comment: That worked really well using PhongMaterial. I was thinking that I missed something while using BufferGeometry and I didn't even think about the actual material used. Many thanks for a good answer!